# Change text box border color in login page as in gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am developing a login page having input filed functionality similar to gmail input field i.e. in focus mode input field should be blue and when validation fails it changes into red, please help.

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried?

Comment: Please also note that I am developing it in asp.net environment.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into the CSS property of [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) to achieve this effect.

HTML:

```
<input class="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
```

CSS:

```
.email:focus {
    border: solid 1px #2196f3;
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: Oh, yea this question should be flagged as too broad. I only half read it. This is more than just a simple HTML/CSS property.